# Autoref not working for elegantbook latex

Tags: hyperref

I have tried creating the autoref name.

```
\documentclass[mode=fancy,lang=en,]{elegantbook}

\newcommand{\propositionautorefname}{Proposition}

\begin{document}
\begin{proposition}\label{pro:first}
    First theorem
\end{proposition}

\autoref{pro:first}
\end{document}
```

[image: Should have been Proposition .1]

Here is the elegantbook class: https://github.com/ElegantLaTeX/ElegantBook/blob/master/elegantbook.cls

Comment: elegantbook.cls has been declared obsolete: https://ctan.org/pkg/elegantbook